# Fail to resize htmlwidget?

Tags: javascript, r, htmlwidgets

I'm trying to figure out how to write the resize method for my `htmlwidget.` I read the instructions, but i'm not sure how to implement the `force.size([width, height]).resume();` part. I tried a few different things but none is working. This is what I have right now:

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'IMPosterior',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    // TODO: define shared variables for this instance

    return {

      renderValue: function(opts) {

        //transition
        var transDuration = 2500;

        var dataDiscrete = opts.bars.map((b, i) => {
            b.y = Number(b.y);
            b.desc = opts.text[i];
            return b;
        });

        var distParams = {
            min: d3.min(opts.data, d => d.x),
            max: d3.max(opts.data, d => d.x)
        };

        distParams.cuts = [-opts.MME, opts.MME, distParams.max];

        opts.data = opts.data.sort((a,b) => a.x - b.x);

        var dataContinuousGroups = [];
        distParams.cuts.forEach((c, i) => {
            let data = opts.data.filter(d => {
                if (i === 0) {
                    return d.x < c;
                } else if (i === distParams.cuts.length - 1) {
                    return d.x > distParams.cuts[i - 1];
                } else {
                    return d.x < c && d.x > distParams.cuts[i - 1];
                }
            });

            data.unshift({x:data[0].x, y:0});
            data.push({x:data[data.length - 1].x, y:0});

            dataContinuousGroups.push({
                color: opts.colors[i],
                data: data
            });
        });

        var margin = {
                top: 50,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 80,
                left: 70
            },
            dims = {
                width: width - margin.left - margin.right,
                height: height - margin.top - margin.bottom
            };

        var xContinuous = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([distParams.min - 1, distParams.max + 1])
            .range([0, dims.width]);

        var xDiscrete = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(dataDiscrete.map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
            .rangeRound([0, dims.width]).padding(0.1);

        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 1])
            .range([dims.height, 0]);

        var svg = d3.select(el).html("").append("svg")
            .attr("width", dims.width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", dims.height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        var g = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
            .scale(xDiscrete);

        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
            .scale(y)
            .ticks(10)
            .tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"));

        var yLabel = g.append("text")
            .attr("class", "y-axis-label")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", -52)
            .attr("x", -160)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .style("font-size", 14 + "px")
            .text("Probability");

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + dims.height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        var areas = g.selectAll(".area")
            .data(dataDiscrete)
            .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "area")
                .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
                .attr("d", function(d, i) {
                    let numPts = dataContinuousGroups[i].data.length - 2;
                    var path = d3.path();
                    path.moveTo(xDiscrete(d.x), y(0));
                    for (j=0; j<numPts; j++) {
                        path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + j*xDiscrete.bandwidth()/(numPts-1), y(d.y));
                    }
                    path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + xDiscrete.bandwidth(), y(0));
                    return path.toString();
                });

        var tooltip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip chart-data-tip')
            .offset([30, 0])
            .direction('s')
            .html(function(d, i) {
                return "<span>" + dataDiscrete[i].desc + "</span>";
            });

        g.call(tooltip);

        areas
            .on('mouseover', tooltip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tooltip.hide);

        var thresholdLine = g.append("line")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
            .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", y(opts.threshold))
            .attr("x2", dims.width)
            .attr("y2", y(opts.threshold));


        var updateXAxis = function(type, duration) {
            if (type === "continuous") {
                xAxis.scale(xContinuous);
            } else {
                xAxis.scale(xDiscrete);
            }
            d3.select(".x").transition().duration(duration).call(xAxis);
        };

        var updateYAxis = function(data, duration) {
            var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });
            extent[0] = 0;
            extent[1] = extent[1] + 0.2*(extent[1] - extent[0]);
            y.domain(extent);
            d3.select(".y").transition().duration(duration).call(yAxis);
        };

        var toggle = function(to, duration) {
            if (to === "distribution") {
                updateYAxis(dataContinuousGroups[0].data.concat(dataContinuousGroups[1].data).concat(dataContinuousGroups[2].data), 0);
                updateXAxis("continuous", duration);

                areas
                    .data(dataContinuousGroups)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                        .attr("d", function(d) {
                            var gen = d3.line()
                                .x(function(p) {
                                    return xContinuous(p.x);
                                })
                                .y(function(p) {
                                    return y(p.y);
                                });
                            return gen(d.data);
                        });

                thresholdLine
                    .style("opacity", 0);

                g.select(".y.axis")
                    .style("opacity", 0);

                g.select(".y-axis-label")
                    .style("opacity", 0);

            } else {
                y.domain([0, 1]);
                d3.select(".y").transition().duration(duration).call(yAxis);

                updateXAxis("discrete", duration);

                areas
                    .data(dataDiscrete)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                        .attr("d", function(d, i) {
                            let numPts = dataContinuousGroups[i].data.length - 2;
                            var path = d3.path();
                            path.moveTo(xDiscrete(d.x), y(0));
                            for (j=0; j<numPts; j++) {
                                path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + j*xDiscrete.bandwidth()/(numPts-1), y(d.y));
                            }
                            path.lineTo(xDiscrete(d.x) + xDiscrete.bandwidth(), y(0));
                            return path.toString();
                        });

                thresholdLine
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .delay(duration)
                        .style("opacity", 1)
                        .attr("y1", y(opts.threshold))
                        .attr("y2", y(opts.threshold));

                g.select(".y.axis")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .delay(duration)
                        .style("opacity", 1);

                g.select(".y-axis-label")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(0)
                    .delay(duration)
                        .style("opacity", 1);
            }
        };


        // Add buttons

        //container for all buttons
        var allButtons = svg.append("g")
          .attr("id", "allButtons");

        //fontawesome button labels
        var labels = ["B", "D"];

        //colors for different button states
        var defaultColor = "#E0E0E0";
        var hoverColor = "#808080";
        var pressedColor = "#000000";

        //groups for each button (which will hold a rect and text)
        var buttonGroups = allButtons.selectAll("g.button")
          .data(labels)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "button")
          .style("cursor", "pointer")
          .on("click", function(d, i) {
            updateButtonColors(d3.select(this), d3.select(this.parentNode));
            d3.select("#numberToggle").text(i + 1);
            if (d === "D") {
                toggle("distribution", transDuration);
            } else {
                toggle("discrete", transDuration);
            }

          })
          .on("mouseover", function() {
            if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
              d3.select(this)
                .select("rect")
                .attr("fill", hoverColor);
            }
          })
          .on("mouseout", function() {
            if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
              d3.select(this)
                .select("rect")
                .attr("fill", defaultColor);
            }
          });

        var bWidth = 40; //button width
        var bHeight = 25; //button height
        var bSpace = 10; //space between buttons
        var x0 = 20; //x offset
        var y0 = 10; //y offset

        //adding a rect to each toggle button group
        //rx and ry give the rect rounded corner
        buttonGroups.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "buttonRect")
          .attr("width", bWidth)
          .attr("height", bHeight)
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return x0 + (bWidth + bSpace) * i;
          })
          .attr("y", y0)
          .attr("rx", 5) //rx and ry give the buttons rounded corners
          .attr("ry", 5)
          .attr("fill", defaultColor);

        //adding text to each toggle button group, centered
        //within the toggle button rect
        buttonGroups.append("text")
          .attr("class", "buttonText")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return x0 + (bWidth + bSpace) * i + bWidth / 2;
          })
          .attr("y", y0 + bHeight / 2)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
          .attr("fill", "white")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d;
          });

        function updateButtonColors(button, parent) {
          parent.selectAll("rect")
            .attr("fill", defaultColor);

          button.select("rect")
            .attr("fill", pressedColor);

        }

        toggle("distribution", 0);

        setTimeout(() => {
            toggle("discrete", transDuration);
        }, 1000);

      },



      resize: function(width, height) {

        // TODO: code to re-render the widget with a new size

        var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
            .attr("width", dims.width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", dims.height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      }

    };
  }
});
```

How can I fix my resize method?

Comment: think the answer will come in https://github.com/ignacio82/IMPosterior/issues/19 in case anyone wants to get involved

Comment: You'll need to write a d3 version of resize/update or just use the viewport. To resize, you'll need to call (again) the scales with the new sizes, the axes with the new scales, and the area with the new scales - probably the text with the new scales. Usually, I find it easiest to write a `draw()` function and simply call that function upon resize.